# Convert RGB mask to JSON for MASK R CNN

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have this mask image.

[image]

From this image, I want to create a JSON file containing the polygon information of different classes. Here different color indicates different classes.

From this image, I want to create a corresponding JSON file. I need help.

I have calculated the sub mask from this image. I took help from the stackoverflow for that as well.

The code is below:

```
def create_sub_masks(mask_image):
    width, height = mask_image.size

    # Initialize a dictionary of sub-masks indexed by RGB colors
    sub_masks = {}
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            # Get the RGB values of the pixel
            pixel = mask_image.getpixel((x,y))[:3]

            # If the pixel is not black...
            if pixel != (0, 0, 0):
                # Check to see if we've created a sub-mask...
                pixel_str = str(pixel)
                sub_mask = sub_masks.get(pixel_str)
                if sub_mask is None:
                   # Create a sub-mask (one bit per pixel) and add to the dictionary
                    # Note: we add 1 pixel of padding in each direction
                    # because the contours module doesn't handle cases
                    # where pixels bleed to the edge of the image
                    sub_masks[pixel_str] = Image.new('1', (width+2, height+2))

                # Set the pixel value to 1 (default is 0), accounting for padding
                sub_masks[pixel_str].putpixel((x+1, y+1), 1)

    return sub_masks
```

So after this I am writing:

```
img = Image.open('sample.jpg')
im2 = create_sub_masks(img)
```

I want a JSON file where:

```html
{
  "version": "5.0.1",
  "flags": {},
  "shapes": [
    {
      "label": "window",
      "points": [
        [
          7.132653061224492,
          62.755102040816325
        ],
        [
          16.316326530612244,
          62.244897959183675
        ],
        [
          31.112244897959187,
          63.26530612244898
        ],
        [
          30.091836734693878,
          89.79591836734694
        ],
        [
          17.846938775510203,
          90.05102040816327
        ],
        [
          6.622448979591837,
          89.54081632653062
        ]
      ],
      "group_id": null,
      "shape_type": "polygon",
      "flags": {}
    },
        "label": "window",
      "points": [
        [
          7.132653061224492,
          62.755102040816325
        ],
        [
          16.316326530612244,
          62.244897959183675
        ],
        [
          31.112244897959187,
          63.26530612244898
        ],
        [
          30.091836734693878,
          89.79591836734694
        ],
        [
          17.846938775510203,
          90.05102040816327
        ],
        [
          6.622448979591837,
          89.54081632653062
        ]
      ],
      "group_id": null,
      "shape_type": "polygon",
      "flags": {}
    },
    ...........
```

In this JSON file, the labels will be created based on my given colour list.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created a sub mask dictionary based on RGB values.

Comment: Good, please click [edit] and add that into your question along with your latest/greatest code.

Comment: Added, please check